# failed to install gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to install `gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf` at Ubuntu, but got the below error:

```
Reading package lists… Done Building dependency tree Reading state
information… Done E: Unable to locate package
gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf E: Couldn’t find any package by
glob ‘gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf’ E: Couldn’t find any
package by regex ‘gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf’
```

Comment: Please visit http://packages.ubuntu.com before trying to blindly install some package(s). Packages with [this exact name are available for 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf&searchon=names). What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @N0rbert I'm running Ubuntu shell in Win 10

Comment: @N0rbert the one at Win 10, it is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Then I can recommend one of the [available packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gcc+multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf&searchon=names).